# How to get list of all applicable methods

Tags: javascript

I just start learning `JavaScript` and I faced with problem: I don't know how to check what exactly I can do with my variables (for example, how I can manage string or array). In `Python` there are very useful methods `dir()` and `help()` that allow user to get list of all applicable methods and find out how to use them:

```
>>>my_number = 1
>>>dir(my_number)
```

This will return

```
['bit_length', 'conjugate', 'denominator', 'from_bytes', 'imag', 'numerator', 'real', 'to_bytes']
```

the list of methods I can apply to `my_number` variable

Then I can get description of each method:

```
>>>help(my_number.real)

Help on int object:

class int(object)
|  int(x=0) -> integer
|  int(x, base=10) -> integer
|
|  Convert a number or string to an integer, or return 0 if no arguments
|  are given.  If x is a number, return x.__int__().  For floating point
|  numbers, this truncates towards zero...
```

So is there any similar function in `JavaScript` so I can call it like `console.log(getAllMethodsFor(myNumber))` ? This could significantly simplify process of language learning...

Comment: [How to display all methods in a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257993/how-to-display-all-methods-in-a-javascript-object) and [Use sinon.js to create a "spy object" with spy methods based ...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025035/use-sinon-js-to-create-a-spy-object-with-spy-methods-based-on-a-real-construct)

Answer (score 2):

you can get the properties of a variable and check if the `typeof` property is a `function`

```
function getAllFunctions(myvar)
{
   var allMethods = [];
   for( var property in myvar)
   {
      if (typeof myvar[property] == "function")
      {
         allMethods.push(property);
      }
   }
   return allMethods ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing built-in, but easy to write:

```js
function dir(obj) {

    if(obj === null)
        return [];

    var uniq = a => a.filter((x, i) => a.indexOf(x) === i);

    return uniq(dir(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)).concat(
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).filter(p => typeof obj[p] === 'function')
    ));

}

document.write(dir(1))
document.write("<hr>");
document.write(dir("abc"))
```

Regarding `help`, there's no such thing either, but typing `mdn <method name>` in google usually does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing by default, but you could write one simply by iterating the properties of the given object:

```
for (var prop in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[prop] == 'function') {
        console.log(prop);
    }
}
```

Having said that, that's still missing the integrated docstrings for `help()`. Typically in Javascript development you're reading the (hopefully) accompanying documentation and/or use an interactive console like Chrome's Web Inspector to inspect objects in a more GUI-like manner.