# Sinon spy on entire module

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

Is there a way to spy on an entire module and check for each function separately? Here is what I mean:

**Normal spying:**

```
let spy1 = sinon.spy(_, 'isString');
let spy2 = sinon.spy(_, 'isArray');

expect(spy1)...
expect(spy2)...
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
let spy = sinon.spy(_);

expect(spy.isString)...
expect(spy.isArray)...
```

but can't quite figure out how.

Thanks,

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [Use sinon.js to create a “spy object” with spy methods based on a real constructor/prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025035/use-sinon-js-to-create-a-spy-object-with-spy-methods-based-on-a-real-construct)

Answer (score 0):

There is no first class support for this with `sinon`, and we're not intending to add first class support for it either.

It's not difficult to do with a few lines of code

```
Object.keys(_).forEach(key => {
  if (typeof _[key] !== 'function') {
    return;
  }
  sinon.spy(_, key)
}
```